# How to save data from array (PHP) to MySQL table? (using MySQLi)

Tags: php, arrays, database, mysqli

Here is generated array:

```
$data = array();
  for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++){
      $data[] = array(
      'name'        => md5(rand()),
      'active'        => rand(0, 1)?'active':'banned',
      'create_date'    => rand(0, 1)?'now':'2014/12/31 14:51:52',
      'income'        => base64_encode(rand(-9999, 9999)),
      );
  }
```

And my try to save this data to database:

```
$columns = implode(", ",array_keys($data));
$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($data));
$values  = implode(", ", $escaped_values);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `data`($columns) VALUES ($values)";
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work, showing this warning: "MYSQL_REAL_ESCAPE_STRING() EXPECTS PARAMETER 1 TO BE STRING, ARRAY GIVEN IN..."

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should write it something like that:

```
'name'        => mysql_real_escape_string(md5(rand())),
```

and delele:

```
$escaped_values = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', array_values($data));
```